# Regex issue for getting second group from string

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I tried with below Regex

**Input string = \nAddress 123 Abc st. Phone (123) 456-7890\nLine2\nLine3\nCity";**

Regex

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"Address(.*)Phone.*\n(.*)City", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

But when I have used given regex at that time in the output I got below result set.

**for first group = 123 Abc st.
for second group = null.**

My expected output is as below but from above regex, I got only result set one but not the second one.

**expected output**

Group 1 = 123 Abc st.

Group 2 = Line2\nLine3

Comment: Use `@"Address(.*)Phone.*?\n(.*)City"`

Comment: It’s not duplicate question

Comment: It is, you just need to use a lazy dot.